# How do I get to this dark blue area in Academia 400AF (South East of the map)?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

I'm at 99% completion for Academia 400AF. I cannot seem to figure out how to get to this tiny dark blue area, that I need to get 100%.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Image:
[image]